# Multiple Plugins in TYPO3 Extension

Tags: typo3, extbase

I try to create an TYPO3 extension with multiple Plugins in TYPO3 8.7 using EXTBASE (With and without Extensionbuilder).

I don't understand why, but the following TypoScript doesn't work:
(Error no Template found...)

```
plugin.tx_test_pi1 {
  view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:test/Resources/Private/Templates/
...
}
plugin.tx_test_pi2 {
  view {
    templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:test/Resources/Private/Templates/
}
```

However, if I made the following changes all PlugIn's will work:

```
plugin.tx_test {
      view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:test/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extbase uses the general TypoScript configuration. The plugins are not separated any more by classes. You can use three plugins and only one controller.

Maybe have a look at this page: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/7-configuring-the-plugin.html

Comment: OK, that's new... 
For sure, the link above is clear and I already read this...
However the current STABLE version of the extension_builder will build the listed code ....

AND reading this, I'm absolutley confused from now:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/62105

Who can tell me what is the right way to set several Plugins in TYPO3 using Extbase?

Comment: OK, I found the problem. In TYPO3 7.6 it was possible to define different PlugIns. Sinze TYPO3 8.7 this is gone. However BUG or FEATURE TYPO3 8.7.3 uses the TS : "plugin.tx_test_pi1" as "plugin.tx_test"!!! It removes the _pi1 automatically ??? Further  "plugin.tx_test_pi2" does not override  "plugin.tx_test"... Sorry that is to high for my small brain...